# Partially log x-axis?

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale, scaling

Sometimes using logarithmic scale for x-axis offers greater detail close to x=0 at the expense of loosing some of the details on the rest of your plot.

In the following working example one faces a delemma between

```
 Plot[1/Abs[x - 5/1000]*1/Abs[x - 7/1000]*Exp[19*x]*Sin[200*x], {x, 0, 
  1}, PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 200, PlotPoints -> 500]
```

and

```
LogLinearPlot[
 1/Abs[x - 5/1000]*1/Abs[x - 7/1000]*Exp[19*x]*Sin[200*x], {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 200, PlotPoints -> 500]
```

A profound way to resolve the situation would be to use logarithmic scaling  up to x=1/10 and then a linear one up to x=1.

Does anyone know whether this is possible or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use an [`Inset`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Inset.html) to zoom in to the [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html). Using `Plot` in the `Inset` is easier to read than using [`LogLinearPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/LogLinearPlot.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Manipulate[
 Plot[
  1/Abs[x - 5/1000]*1/Abs[x - 7/1000]*
   Exp[19*x]*Sin[200*x],
  {x, 0, 1},
  PlotRange -> All,
  WorkingPrecision -> 200,
  PlotPoints -> 500,
  MaxRecursion -> 5,
  Frame -> True,
  ImageSize -> Large,
  Epilog -> {Inset[
     plt[
      1/Abs[x - 5/1000]*1/Abs[x - 7/1000]*
       Exp[19*x]*Sin[200*x],
      {x, 0, 0.01},
      PlotRange -> All,
      WorkingPrecision -> 200,
      PlotPoints -> 500,
      MaxRecursion -> 5,
      Frame -> True,
      ImageSize -> 300],
     {0.37, -9.5*^7}]}],
 {{plt, Plot}, {Plot, LogLinearPlot}}]
```

[image]